# ESP32: Error when trying to connect to Web server via Wifi while Bluetooth is on: bcn_timout, alloc fail

Tags: esp32

I'm writing firmware for a custom board using the ESP32. I'm getting the following errors when trying to connect to a server with HTTPS while Bluetooth is running. I'm using the latest IDF v3.0 commit I believe. I ran git pull on esp-idf right before testing this. Once the issue occurs, wifi disconnects and is unable to reconnect. I've combed through forums and issues trying to find a solution, but I'm stumped. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I've seen these error messages pop up in the issue tracker a few times for other bugs.

I've basically worked off of examples to this point so it's mainly using the Bluetooth GATT Server table example, in conjunction with the HTTPS Request example. If I set Bluetooth to disconnect when Wifi obtains an IP address, the Https code starts like expected and no crash occurs. Has anyone encountered this and have a suggestion?

```
I (185) cpu_start: Pro cpu up.
I (185) cpu_start: Starting app cpu, entry point is 0x40081124
0x40081124: call_start_cpu1 at C:/esp-idf/components/esp32/cpu_start.c:225

I (0) cpu_start: App cpu up.
I (188) heap_init: Initializing. RAM available for dynamic allocation:
I (195) heap_init: At 3FFAFF10 len 000000F0 (0 KiB): DRAM
I (201) heap_init: At 3FFD2AF8 len 0000D508 (53 KiB): DRAM
I (207) heap_init: At 3FFE0440 len 00003BC0 (14 KiB): D/IRAM
I (214) heap_init: At 3FFE4350 len 00013CB0 (79 KiB): D/IRAM
I (220) heap_init: At 40093BE8 len 0000C418 (49 KiB): IRAM
I (226) cpu_start: Pro cpu start user code
I (19) esp_apptrace: Initialized TRAX on CPU0
I (20) pm_esp32: Frequency switching config: CPU_MAX: 240, APB_MAX: 240, APB_MIN: XTAL, Light sleep: DISABLED
I (25) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on PRO CPU.
I (68) esp_apptrace: Initialized TRAX on CPU1
I (5) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on APP CPU.
I (51) Main App (main): Start App
Device Name: Gunbox Pro
Firmware Version: R003541_00aa

I (118) Bluetooth Driver (dBluetooth): Initializing Bluetooth Driver
I (125) system_api: Base MAC address is not set, read default base MAC address from BLK0 of EFUSE
I (381) phy: phy_version: 383.0, 79a622c, Jan 30 2018, 15:38:06, 0, 0
I (422) Bluetooth Driver (dBluetooth): Bluetooth Driver Initialized
I (422) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): Initializing Bluetooth Interface
I (426) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): GATTS Profile Event Server reg event
I (439) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): create attribute table successfully, the number handle = 16

I (447) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): create attribute table successfully, the number handle = 28

I (454) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): gap event handler: 0
I (460) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): gap event handler: 1
I (469) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): SERVICE_START_EVT, status 0, service_handle 40
I (475) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): SERVICE_START_EVT, status 0, service_handle 56
I (484) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): gap event handler: 6
I (490) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): advertising start successfully
I (498) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): Bluetooth Interface initialized successfully
I (506) WiFi Driver (dWifi): Start ESP32_Wifi_Driver_Init
I (514) wifi: wifi firmware version: ebd3e5d
I (516) wifi: config NVS flash: enabled
I (520) wifi: config nano formating: disabled
I (524) system_api: Base MAC address is not set, read default base MAC address from BLK0 of EFUSE
I (533) system_api: Base MAC address is not set, read default base MAC address from BLK0 of EFUSE
I (565) wifi: Init dynamic tx buffer num: 32
I (565) wifi: Init data frame dynamic rx buffer num: 32
I (565) wifi: Init management frame dynamic rx buffer num: 32
I (569) wifi: wifi driver task: 3ffe3c7c, prio:23, stack:4096
I (574) wifi: Init static rx buffer num: 10
I (578) wifi: Init dynamic rx buffer num: 32
I (582) wifi: wifi power manager task: 0x3ffe8c40 prio: 21 stack: 2560
I (600) wifi: mode : sta (24:0a:c4:83:13:64)
I (601) WiFi Driver (dWifi): Task started
I (601) WiFi Driver (dWifi): SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_START
I (601) ESP32 HTTPS Driver (dESP32_HTTPS): Seeding the random number generator
I (613) ESP32 HTTPS Driver (dESP32_HTTPS): Loading the CA root certificate...
I (622) ESP32 HTTPS Driver (dESP32_HTTPS): Setting hostname for TLS session...
I (628) ESP32 HTTPS Driver (dESP32_HTTPS): Setting up the SSL/TLS structure...
I (9317) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_CONNECT_EVT, conn_id = 0
I (9317) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): 5a e7 22 d4 8d 6f
I (9734) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): gap event handler: 20
I (9734) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): update connetion params status = 0, min_int = 16, max_int = 32,conn_int = 24,latency = 0, timeout = 400
I (9825) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_MTU_EVT, MTU 500
I (10425) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (10425) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 1, handle 42

I (10427) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): Base MAC: **:**:**:**:**:**
I (10545) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (10545) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 2, handle 45

I (10665) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (10665) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 3, handle 48

I (10875) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (10875) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 4, handle 51

I (11535) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (11535) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 5, handle 43

I (11595) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (11595) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 6, handle 46

I (11655) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (11655) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 7, handle 49

I (11715) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (11715) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 8, handle 52

I (11775) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (11775) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 9, handle 59

I (11835) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (11835) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 10, handle 62

I (11895) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (11895) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 11, handle 65

I (11955) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (11955) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 12, handle 68

I (12015) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (12015) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 13, handle 71

I (12075) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (12075) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 14, handle 74

I (12135) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (12135) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 15, handle 77

I (12195) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (12195) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 16, handle 80

I (12255) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (12255) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 17, handle 83

I (13724) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (13725) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 18, handle 58

I (17025) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): Wifi Control Write
Wifi Control Write msg: cmdWifiConn=      NetworkName,NetworkPassword

I (17074) WiFi Driver (dWifi): Start ESP32_Wifi_Driver_Connect

I (17104) WiFi Driver (dWifi): Wifi Config Bit Detected

I (17145) Bluetooth Interface (iBluetooth): ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT
E (17145) BT: GATT_INFO_READ_EVT, conn_id 0, trans_id 21, handle 58

I (17230) wifi: n:1 0, o:1 0, ap:255 255, sta:1 0, prof:1
I (17896) wifi: state: init -> auth (b0)
I (17900) wifi: state: auth -> assoc (0)
I (17904) wifi: state: assoc -> run (10)
I (17921) wifi: connected with NetworkName, channel 1
I (19018) event: sta ip: 10.**.***.105, mask: 255.255.255.0, gw: 10.**.***.1
I (19018) WiFi Driver (dWifi): SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP
Wifi Serv char status read val changed to : 1
System got IP: wifiServVal: 1
I (19027) ESP32 HTTPS Driver (dESP32_HTTPS): Connected to AP
I (19027) WiFi Driver (dWifi): Wifi Config Good Bit Detected

I (19034) ESP32 HTTPS Driver (dESP32_HTTPS): Connecting to www.howsmyssl.com:443...
I (19168) ESP32 HTTPS Driver (dESP32_HTTPS): Connected.
I (19168) ESP32 HTTPS Driver (dESP32_HTTPS): Performing the SSL/TLS handshake...
I (20905) wifi: pm start, type:0

I (26491) wifi: bcn_timout,ap_probe_send_start
W (26491) wifi: alloc eb len=76 type=2 fail

W (26491) wifi: m f probe req l=0

W (26992) wifi: alloc eb len=76 type=2 fail

W (26992) wifi: m f probe req l=0

W (27492) wifi: alloc eb len=76 type=2 fail

W (27492) wifi: m f probe req l=0

W (27992) wifi: alloc eb len=76 type=2 fail

W (27993) wifi: m f probe req l=0

W (28493) wifi: alloc eb len=76 type=2 fail

W (28493) wifi: m f probe req l=0

I (28993) wifi: ap_probe_send over, resett wifi status to disassoc
I (28993) wifi: state: run -> init (1)
I (28994) wifi: pm stop, total sleep time: 0/8088689

I (28994) wifi: n:1 0, o:1 0, ap:255 255, sta:1 0, prof:1
I (29002) WiFi Driver (dWifi): SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED
Wifi Serv char status read val changed to : 0
I (31422) WiFi Driver (dWifi): SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED
Wifi Serv char status read val changed to : 0
I (33833) WiFi Driver (dWifi): SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED
Wifi Serv char status read val changed to : 0
I (36243) WiFi Driver (dWifi): SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED
Wifi Serv char status read val changed to : 0
...
This continues forever
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appeared to have to do with WiFi and Bluetooth Coexistence not being supported in versions of the ESP-IDF prior to the v3.1 beta. I believe the two together use most of the onboard RAM, then the mbed tls library needs way more RAM than is available. In case anyone is curious, a way to workaround this is to disconnect and deallocate Bluetooth right before calling the tls functions, then deallocate tls when done and reinit Bluetooth. It's annoying, but it works. The esp-idf v3.1 beta is supposed to have fixed this, but I haven't gotten around to testing.

Comment: Can't say anything about the v3.1 beta and prior, but the thing is actually related to the antenna. The antenna is used by BT and WIFI at the same time. But only one can actually use it. I have a topic open here on how to achieve a2dp sink with wifi sending coexistence https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55865909/acquire-a-semaphore-for-the-esp32-antenna-bluetooth-wifi-dualmode

Comment: @Dimfred I haven't used a2dp with the ESP32, but I've been using BLE and wifi pretty extensively and haven't really had an issue with them both using the antenna since I posted this last year. More recent versions of the IDF + some optimizations on my end have solved all the issues I was having.

Comment: Okay I see. Is the code you worked on open source? Would it be possible to see it?

Comment: @Dimfred Unfortunately it's not. It's full proprietary firmware for a few different consumer products. It really didn't require any crazy tweaking or anything though. The BLE and WiFi stacks are both running on Core 0 (Pro CPU) with the rest of the app running on Core 1 (App CPU). I'm not using the software controlled BLE/WiFi coexistence control, but you may want to look into that because that is recommended for heavy traffic scenarios. It's a common practice for electronics to have one antenna that is used by BLE and WiFi, so it really shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: That is really a pity. Yea I am using the software controlled scenario. The thing is I have no control over the a2dp task no semaphore for it. And the a2dp task is the blocking one he releases really rarely. But I will play around. Thank you for your comments!