# acquire a semaphore for the esp32 antenna (bluetooth/wifi dualmode)

Tags: freertos, esp32

I am trying to build a esp32 application, where I have bluetooth and wifi enabled at the same time.

Bluetooth is used with the a2dp profile, where the esp is a sink. After receiving the data, it should be published over a UDP socket as a broadcast to the network.

The problem is the antenna. Both bt and wifi are sharing it. The a2dp stream seems to permanently acquiring the antenna and releasing it very rarely (~2 packages/min, I have ~3000 packages/min).

So my question: Is there some kind of semaphore, which can be acquired to have the full control over the antenna? So my socket would be able to send the data to the network?

I am using my esp32 with freeRTOS. The freeRTOS lib is written in C, but I am trying to wrap everything in C++. Still I think this problem is related to a C lib so I tag it with C.

I am open for any suggestions how to build that. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**:

I am using `release/v3.3` from the official `esp-idf` repo.

I have: `CONFIG_SW_COEXIST_ENABLE=y` and `CONFIG_SW_COEXIST_PREFERENCE_WIFI=y`

I can't find `CONFIG_ESP32_WIFI_SW_COEXIST_ENABLE` in my config.

The mentioned configuration doesn't work.

I tried reading the post, but can't find any "`scan_window`" or "`scan_interval`" in my lib. It was written that it is somewhere in the `gap_api` but can't find it.

Here is my code + config: https://github.com/Dimfred/esp32_bt_streamer

The socket client task, which should broadcast the `a2dp_msg`, is started here:
https://github.com/Dimfred/esp32_bt_streamer/blob/master/main/app/event_handler.cpp#L22

All events popped from station/access point/bluetooth/a2dp are all caught in event_handler.hpp/cpp

Comment: are you using esp-idf?

Comment: Yes I am using esp-idf.

Comment: Just because you might be using C as a programming interface this has nothing to do with C as a language. Otherwise you could also tag your question "English" or "keyboard"

Answer (score 3):

As you saw, Bluetooth has higher priority on WIFI.

Have a look at [CONFIG_SW_COEXIST_ENABLE](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/kconfig.html#config-sw-coexist-enable) and make sure it is enabled. You also need to configure [CONFIG_SW_COEXIST_PREFERENCE](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/kconfig.html#config-sw-coexist-preference) to WIFI. Please see the page for additional flags that you could update depending on your application.

If you want to leave the hardware responsible for handling the co-existing devices (BL and WIFI), you can disable `CONFIG_SW_COEXIST_ENABLE` and reduce the scan window and increase the scan interval of the BL to leave time for WIFI to get access to the antenna. See this [post](https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=2291) for more details.

To answer your original question about a possible semaphore/mutex. I doubt there is one accessible for you to use and I would leave the API (software) handling the co-existing modules accessing the antenna. But you can always checkout what the code is doing once `CONFIG_SW_COEXIST_ENABLE` is set (the flag is renamed to `CONFIG_ESP32_WIFI_SW_COEXIST_ENABLE`). See https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/81ca1c01395f604972fbf141cfbe49764a746023/components/esp_wifi/src/phy_init.c

Comment: I allready tried changing the priority to WiFi this had nno effect. Coexist is enabled. Thank you for the post about the disabling of coexistence I will dig into that. I am currently low on time, but will try it as asap.

Comment: If nothing worked, please update the questions or add comments with what you tried.