# Making ESP32 WiFi/Bluetooth work together

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++

I'm creating a App that involves Bluetooth and WiFi. I firstly connect the Phone to the Bluetooth and pass the WiFi ssid and password through it. Then after receiving the ssid and the password I attempt to connect it to the WiFi. I manage to store the ssid and password into a char array. 
After sending the data from Bluetooth, and the ESP32 making the connection with the WiFi, the Bluetooth gets disconnected. I can't connect the Bluetooth again because WiFi is connected, since I control certain statements from the code via Bluetooth.read(), I will need to allow the connection to coexist between WiFi and Bluetooth.

**The project consist on SPIFFS (Flash memory saving). The WiFi ssid and password are passed from Bluetooth firstly, then, I make the connection from the Bluetooth data received into a char array, so I can connect it to the internet later on.**

I thought firstly on adding a callback that alerts when the device is attempting to connect, but couldn't find in the documentation any code that was able to do so. I have a callback function that tells me when the device connects and disconnects.

I searched up and found something about `Menuconfig` but I couldn't find where it was located.

This is what I was reading from: https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/ESP32_FAQs__EN.pdf

```
5.3.2.
How do ESP32 Bluetooth and Wi-Fi coexist?
In the menuconfig menu, there is a special option called “Software controls WiFi/ 
Bluetooth coexistence”, which is used to control the ESP32's Bluetooth and Wi-Fi 
coexistence using software, thus balancing the coexistence requirement for controlling 
the RF module by both the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth modules. Please note that if Option 
“Software controls WiFi/Bluetooth coexistence” is enabled, the BLE scan 
interval shall not exceed 0x100 slots (about 160 ms).
```

I couldn't find where `menuconfig` was located.

I'm using the ```BluetoothSerial.h`` library

This is a piece of the code:

```
// ------------------------------ Inicialização do loop ------------------------------ //
void loop() {
  // Preparando String para enviar ao usuario
  line_one_length = line_one.length();
  line_two_length = line_two.length();
  line_three_length = line_three.length();

  char receive_line_one[line_one_length], receive_line_two[line_two_length], receive_line_three[line_three_length];
  char receive_wifi_ssid[line_one_length], receive_wifi_pass[line_two_length];
  
  String deletar;
  
  file = SPIFFS.open("/wifi.txt");

  // ------------------------------ Ve se o usuario digitou a palavra deletar ------------------------------ //
  if (SerialBT.available()){
    while (SerialBT.available()) {
      insert_chars = SerialBT.read();
      deletar = String(deletar + insert_chars);
    }
    deletar.trim();
  }

  // ------------------------------ Conexão ao WiFi ------------------------------ //
  if (line_one != "" and wifi_state == 0 and receive_wifi_ssid != ""){
    line_one.toCharArray(receive_wifi_ssid, line_one_length);
    line_two.toCharArray(receive_wifi_pass, line_two_length);
    delay(100);
    WiFi.begin(receive_wifi_ssid, receive_wifi_pass);
    Serial.println("Conectando ao WiFi...");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(1000);
    }
    Serial.println("\nConectado ao WiFi");
    wifi_state = 1;
  }

  Serial.print("Estado: ");
  Serial.println(connection_state);

  // ------------------------------ Vê se a conteudo dentro do FILE ------------------------------ //
  if (file.size() > 0) {
    if (deletar == "deletar"){
      delete_file_info();
      wifi_ssid = "";
      wifi_password = "";
      database_info = "";
      line_one = "";
      line_two = "";
      line_three = "";
      wifi_state = 0;
      Serial.println("Arquivo deletado com sucesso");
      return;
    }
    read_file_info();
    all_lines();
  }else{  
    if (wifi_ssid == "" and connection_state == 0 and line_one == ""){
      Serial.print("File size: ");
      Serial.print(file.size());
      Serial.println(", O valor dentro da string é nulo, nada será adicionado ao arquivo");
      delay(1000);
    }else if (connection_state == 1 and line_one == ""){
      // Chamando a função para armazenar os dados do usuario dentro do FILE
      bluetooth_while_loop();
    }
  }
  
  file.close();
  delay(3000);
```

**What I needed was to be able to make a connection between WiFi and Bluetooth simultaneously.**

Answer (score 4):

The `menuconfig` is [here](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/ef99cd7fe7778719c92d6f8df0f10d3f0f7aa35e/tools/sdk/include/config/sdkconfig.h#L23). The code for software WiFi/BL coexistence is [here](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/81ca1c01395f604972fbf141cfbe49764a746023/components/esp_wifi/src/phy_init.c#L168). And the related issue is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55865909/acquire-a-semaphore-for-the-esp32-antenna-bluetooth-wifi-dualmode). Because WiFi and Bluetooth use the same antenna, i wouldn't recommend doing WiFi/BL coexistence altogether. Instead, you may use `WiFi.setMode(WiFi_AP_STA)` to instantiate `SoftAP` mode and `STA` mode simultaneously.
Try the code below to instantiate both `softAP` and `STA` mode:

```
#include <WiFi.h>

void setup(){
  WiFi.setMode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  WiFi.begin("my-sta-ssid", "my-sta-pass");
  WiFi.softAP("my-ap-ssid", "my-ap-pass");
}

void loop(){}
```

You can create simple `WebServer` to do "runtime configuration" things.

Comment: I need to be able to use Bluetooth and WiFi, but the point is, when I attempt to realize a Bluetooth connection with the ESP, I would need to disconnect the WiFi (When attempting to connect the Bluetooth), and after sending the data from Bluetooth I could disconnect the Bluetooth so the WiFi can take control of the antenna. I don't think that softAP would solve my problem since I don't need a access point. Maybe STA can solve the problem, but I'm not sure...

Comment: I had a similar problem. Using WiFi to find get some clients and then sharing a BT-UUID so that only the selected client had access to the ESP device. I now use 2 ESPs: one with WiFi and one with BT connected via serial interface. Maybe this could be a solution for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. Your question remains, but your use case though..  Seems a lot like [BluFi](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/blufi.html).

> The BluFi for ESP32 is a Wi-Fi network configuration function via Bluetooth channel. It provides a secure protocol to pass Wi-Fi configuration and credentials to ESP32. Using this information, ESP32 can then connect to an AP or establish a SoftAP.

> Fragmenting, data encryption, and checksum verification in the BluFi layer are the key elements of this process.